# Find the mistake in $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n}=1 \Rightarrow 1=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

It is obvious that we have:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}1=1.$$
But let us now write this sum in two ways, let $a_n=x^n$ and $b_n=x^{2n}+x^{2n+1}$ we thus have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$. We can write the above limit as:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{N} b_n} = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{N} b_n},
$$
where we can swap limits because of the [Moore-Osgood Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moore-Osgood_Theorem). We now find for the right hand side:
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{N} b_n}=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{N+1}{2(N+1)}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
This shows that $1=\frac{1}{2}$ which is clearly incorrect, but I do not see where the error occurs, I guess it is in the step where the Moore-Osgood Theorem is applied where we define $f_N(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{N} b_n}$.

EDIT: I believe I have found the error, in order to apply the Moore-Osgood Theorem we need uniform convergence from $f_N(x)$ to $f(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n}$ but this $f$ is not continuous, therefore we can not apply Dini's theorem to show that pointwise convergence implies uniform convegence.

Comment: Are you sure that Moore-Osgood Theorem applies there? (disclaimer, I have not idea what it is about)

Comment: Why is $f_N$ uniformly convergent?

Comment: If we let $x$ vary in $[0,1]$ It seems to me that we have pointwise convergence and then this convergence is also uniform BUT: I believe I see the error! The limit function is not continuous as it is $1$ everywhere while it is $1/2$ in $1$!

Comment: $f_N(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{N+1}}$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ which you need to apply that theorem. For example you can see this as as uniform convergence implies continuity of the limit and here $f_N(x) \to 1$ if $x<1$ and to $f_N(1) \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Winther Yes indeed! Good very interesting! Thank you

Comment: Even though Euler Pythagoras named the formal reason, you can already anticipate why it is breaking down there. Consider
$$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{N} b_n} = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n}{\sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} a_n} = \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x^{2N+2}}$$ and fix $x<1$, then in the limit $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} x^{N+1} = 0$ and $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} x^{2N+2} = 0$, so the ratio is $1$. This is because the series is unformly convergent for all $x\in[0,c] \forall c<1$, but first taking the limit $x\rightarrow 1$ obviously gives $1/2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the *Moore-Osgood Theorem*, you must make sure that $(f_n)_{n \geq 0}$ converges uniformly toward $f$.

$i.e. \sup\limits_{[0,1]}|f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$.

This is not the case here.